# Search for a string and print the line in a different order using Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I need to write a shell script that does the following which I am showing below with an example.

Suppose I have a file `cars.txt` which depicts a table like this
`Person|Car|Country`
The '|' is the separator. So the first two lines goes like this

```
Michael|Ford|USA
Rahul|Maruti|India
```

I have to write a shell script which will find the lines in the `cars.txt` file that has the country as USA and will print it like

```
USA|Ford|Michael
```

I am not very adept with Unix so I need some help here.

Comment: What efforts have you made so far?

Answer (score -1):

Will this do?

```
while read -r i; do
  NAME="$(cut -d'|' -f1 <<<"$i")"
  MAKE="$(cut -d'|' -f2 <<<"$i")"
  COUNTRY="$(cut -d'|' -f3 <<<"$i")"
  echo "$COUNTRY|$MAKE|$NAME"
done < <(grep "USA$" cars.txt)
```

Comment: Could you test it yourself and tell me? I tried but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: 1. Don't abuse `cat`s. It's `grep "USA$" cars.txt`. Don't you like cats? 2. `for i in $(cat)` is syntactically wrong. Use `while read -r i; do .... done < ..`

Comment: @Tuhin Yeah It works on Ubuntu. Here's the screenshot: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12-Bu-AgXYaByKZYhIyt5NP8o2H7sYMTO

Answer (score -1):

**Updated To Locate `USA` Not 1st Line As Provided in Your Question**

Using `awk` you can do what you are attempting in a very simple manner, e.g.

```
$ awk -F'|' '/USA/ {for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--) printf "%s%s", $i, i==1 ? RS : FS}' cars.txt
USA|Ford|Michael
India|Maruti|Rahul
```

**Explanation**

- `awk -F'|'` read the file using `'|'` as the *Field-Separator*, specified as `-F'|'` at the beginning of the call, or as `FS` within the command itself,
- `/USA/` locate only lines containing `"USA"`,
- `for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--)` - loop over fields in reverse order,
- `printf "%s%s", $i, i==1 ? RS : FS` - output the field followed by a `'|'` (`FS`) if `i` is not equal `1` or by the *Record-Separator* (`RS`) which is a `"\n"` by default if `i` is equal `1`. The form `test ? true_val : false_val` is just the *ternary* operator that tests if `i == 1` and if so provides `RS` for output, otherwise provides `FS` for output.

It will be orders of magnitude faster than spawning 8-subshells using *command substitutions*, `grep` and `cut` (plus the pipes).

**Printing Only The 1st Occurrence of Line Containing `"USA"`**

To print only the first line with `"USA"`, all you need to do is `exit` after processing, e.g.

```
$ awk -F'|' '/USA/ {for (i = NF; i >= 1; i--) printf "%s%s", $i, i==1 ? RS : FS; exit}' cars.txt
USA|Ford|Michael
```

**Explanation**

- simply adding `exit` to the end of the command will cause `awk` to stop processing records after the first one.

While both `awk` and `sed` take a little time to make friends with, together they provide the Unix-Swiss-Army-Knife for text processing. Well worth the time to learn both. It only takes a couple of hours to get a good base by going through one of the tutorials. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: David I need to print the lines which has country as USA. Not print the entire file. Will your solution work still? If not, can you modify it?

Comment: Not the first line, the line that contains country USA.

Comment: @glennjackman Really? A DV given ambiguous example data stating `"So the first two lines goes like this"` and question misunderstanding?

Comment: The OP says in both the Q and the comment "has country as USA". Seems pretty obvious to me.

Comment: `" I need to print the lines which has country as USA"` and here are my first two lines. I see it now, but it was not that obvious originally and there certainly wasn't any technical inaccuracy in the answer.

Comment: Yeah @glennjackman is right. I need to print all the lines which has country has USA. I only showed the first two lines as an example but I thought I was pretty clear that I need all the lines.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidC.Rankin Will check and give an update here.